# How to order records according to an attribute from associated model - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Grade` model and a `Course` model with the following associations:

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
    resourcify
    has_many :courses
end


class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    resourcify
    belongs_to :grade
    has_many :chapters, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :packages, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :subject
end
```

I have a grade_number column in my Grade table, and I would like it so that when I display all courses in course index page, they are ordered by grade_number in descending order. Here is my course#index:

```
      def index
       @grades = Grade.all
       @subjects = Subject.all
       @courses = Course.includes(:grades).order("grade.grade_number DESC")
      end
```

Which is giving me the following error:

> Association named 'grades' was not found on Course; perhaps you
>   misspelled it?

and index.html.erb :

```
        <% @courses.each do |course| %>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="course_info">
              <div class="top_titles">Grade <%= course.grade.grade_number %></div>
              <div class="subject"><%= course.subject.name if course.subject and course.subject.name%></div>  
              <div class="semester"><%= course.semester %> Semester</div>
              <div class="button_wrapper"><%= link_to "View Course", [course.grade, course], :class => "course_button" %></div>
              <% if can? :update, :destroy, @course %>
                <div class="admin-links">
                  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_grade_course_path(course.grade, course) %> |
                  <%= link_to 'Destroy', [course.grade, course], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                </div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: `@courses = Course.includes(:grade).order("grade.grade_number DESC")`  have you tried using this ?  - `includes` should take exactly the name of your association. Instead of `grades`, try changing to `grade` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  def index
       @grades = Grade.all
       @subjects = Subject.all
       @courses = Course.includes(:grade).order("grades.grade_number DESC")
  end
```

Please note that Association name in `Course` is `grade` not `grades` 
Course belongs to grade so it is singular.

Comment: Thanks this worked, however for some bizzare reason im getting ascending order when i use DESC and vice versa. Would you happen to know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

removes `s` in `:grades`

```
@courses = Course.includes(:grade).order("grades.grade_number DESC")
```

it will work. try like this.

Comment: I think it's `includes(:grade)` and `order("grades...")`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @tadman

`includes` should take association name and `order` should take table name i.e

```
courses = Course.includes(:grade).order("grades.grade_number DESC")
```